# Trigger an INSERT query when mailto: or tel: links are clicked

Tags: javascript, php, mobile, mysqli

I have a php page which is designed around mobile functionality and loads information from search criteria, information is gathered on the page and that information is then POSTed automatically to a database when the page opens to record the visit and works flawlessly, this is the code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `analytics_scans` (`ip_address`, `property_id`, `address`, `town`, `agent_name`, `office`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sissss', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $id, $address, $town,     $agent, $office);
$stmt->execute();
```

On this page are 3 'buttons/images' Call, Mail and Share what I want to do is record these events into 3 separate tables exactly as in the code above without leaving the page, I can't reload it because it will record a further page visit.
I can't duplicate the one shown and point to the other tables as it's the click it has to record.

Ideally something like an onClick function would be the solution but I'm sure that's not possible without leaving the page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: OnClick won't leave the page if it returns False

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ajax (with jQuery for example).

Example:

```
<a href="mailto:xxx@xxx.de" onclick="return javascript:log('mail_clicked');">Write email</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return javascript:log('share_clicked');">Share</a>
```

In jQuery:

```
function log(action) {
    $.get('./log.php?action=' + action);
    return true;
}
```

---

In the log.php:

```
<?php

$db = new MySQLi(...);
if($_GET['action'] == "mail_clicked")
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `mail_clicked` ...");
else if($_GET['action'] == "share_clicked")
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `share_clicked` ...");

?>
```

Comment: Hi @Richard, thanks for your time, so am I correct that this example will use log.php to process the query and return to the page (without having actually left it) but still the tel: command will dial the number or the mailto: command will open up the mail client?

Comment: @IanPither: Yes, it will call the `log()` function at click, which do a GET request to a file (in this case log.php). This file handles the action log. It this is done, `true` will be returned and the link will be called. Please note, that this of course only works with activated JavaScript. (You can use `document.write` for the links if you want to show the links only to JavaScript activated users. Please note that you cannot be sure that the link is _not_ clicked - it's no problem to bypass the log for experienced users. Therefore, it is not useable for security critical applications.)

Comment: Thanks @Richard a very thorough answer and really helpful, I will implement your suggestion and hopefully it will solve my headache.

Comment: @IanPither: No problem. If it does, do not hesitate to mark my answer as solution :-)